# Returning multiple records using first/earliest date

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

This is a simple concept but the LINQ/SQL solution has me stumped!

In the example data below, for each ID I need to retrieve one `ISRC`, taking the earliest dated one for each.

The data is sorted by `ID/ReleaseDate/ISRC`, so I could read the first/top record for each ID.
ie ID 1 = **GBMNA1600001**, ID 2 = **GBMNA1600002**, ID 3 = **GBMNA1600003**, ID 20 = **GBMNA1680058**...

```
ID  ProductID   ISRC    ReleaseDate
1   16  GBMNA1600001    2016-03-27 00:00:00.0000000
1   26  GBMNA1680038    2016-04-24 00:00:00.0000000
1   32  GBMNA1680057    2016-05-01 00:00:00.0000000
1   132 GBMNA1680482    2016-11-13 00:00:00.0000000
1   223 GBMNA1781107    2017-03-26 00:00:00.0000000
2   5   GBMNA1600002    2016-02-14 00:00:00.0000000
2   32  GBMNA1680049    2016-05-01 00:00:00.0000000
3   13  GBMNA1600003    2016-03-13 00:00:00.0000000
3   38  GBMNA1680095    2016-05-29 00:00:00.0000000
3   485 GBMNA1880099    2018-06-26 00:00:00.0000000
20  32  GBMNA1680058    2016-05-01 00:00:00.0000000
20  39  GBMNA1680084    2016-05-29 00:00:00.0000000
20  116 GBMNA1680399    2016-10-30 00:00:00.0000000
20  281 GBMNA1780886    2017-06-05 00:00:00.0000000
20  360 GBMNA1600028    2018-01-08 00:00:00.0000000
```

But I don't know where to start with the LINQ syntax, or even figure out the SQL it should create.

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.0 with EF, code is C# and db is SQL server 2016.

It's in a table I reference using a dbcontext, so I'm starting with

```
var earliestISRCS = from i in _context.allISRCS
                    select i;
```

I've tried using `MIN()` for the date, or sorting the data and using `.FirstOrDefault()` or `Take(1)` but only manage to get one record back.

What I need is to return a set of data - the earliest `ISRC` per `ID`.

If there happens to be more than one `ISRC` for the same date then the sort order of `ISRCS` will additionally be used to determine the first one.

Comment: Are the ISRC values unique? It's hard to tell from the sample data you posted.

Comment: As an aside, your `ID` values are not unique.. that betrays the meaning of "ID" (for "identity").

Comment: Group by, Min, problem solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results) and [`Min`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352408(v=vs.110).aspx) methods. Something like this:

```
var result = from d in _context.allISRCS
             group d by d.ID into grouped
             let min = grouped.Min(d => d.ReleaseDate)
             select new {
                 ID = grouped.Key,
                 _context.allISRCS.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ReleaseDate == min)?.ISRC
             };
```

Comment: This sample code was very useful to follow. I've not used the 'let' clause so it's great to learn something new which will be useful for future development. I just had to add another condition ...FirstOrDefault(c => c.ReleaseDate == min &&  c.ID ==  grouped.Key) to make sure I was getting data for the relevant track. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try following :

```
var earliestISRCS = _context.allISRCS
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.ReleaseDate)
    .GroupBy(x => x.ID)
    .Select(x => x.First())
    .OrderBy(x => x.ID)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thanks for alternative code. I just had to amend and use .OrderBy(x => x.ReleaseDate).ThenBy(x => x.ISRC) to ensure x.First() returned the correct data.